# side chain (polygon) and a ZK (polygonZK EVM or ZK sync)

Tags: polygon, l2, zkevm

The project have to choose an L2 chain to use as a basis, but is very worried. We are torn between a side chain (polygon) and a ZK (polygonZK EVM or ZK sync). In our project, we have adopted account abstraction and do not want users to pay for gas as much as possible. Although side chain has the advantage of lower gas costs and faster processing compared to roll-up,But I think the factors that make roll-up inferior to side chain in terms of gas costs and speed are something that will be resolved with future updates(like dencun) to L1. I am more sympathetic to roll-up than side-chain in terms of technology.

If it's sidechain(polygon) vs. zkrollup, which should I choose?